# Combine factors into single list

Tags: r

I have some data about the title of faculties in our college

[image: data of title]

I want to find all the titles and only list the ones that are unique, e.g. Professor, Assistant Teaching Professor, Instructor.

For instance. make "Distinguished Professor' and 'professor' have the same factor "professor"

Simply, it just like combine two factors to one factor

Comment: will adding a new column to your data work? you can easily do that with ifelse statement. Also, not very clear...if you only want the unique levels `unique(df$x)` should give you the levels of factor `x` on data.frame `df`

Answer (score 0):

If I have a data set with 5 factor levels, I can change the levels by just renaming those columns:

```
set.seed(23)
x <- factor(sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE))
x
#  [1] c b b d e c e e e e e d b b e a c c e d
# Levels: a b c d e
levels(x)[3] <- "new_level"
x
#  [1] a b b d e a e e e e e d b b e a a a e d
# Levels: a b d e
```

The number of levels will automatically be reduced, as shown.